# How to preview location of image on Albums on iPad?

Tags: ipad, preview, geolocation, photos.app

I am able to see image's location on Photos tab on iPad, but how to preview the same in Albums tag using iOS 8 Photos app?

Answer (score 1):

I use the [View Exif app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id945320815) to extend the Photos app to have geo mapping visuals. It shows all the exif information I've ever needed so I'm quite happy with the value.

I'm interested if there's another way, but this works great for me.